# why react native expo open on android web browser

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I run some expo test project on android. when i install project it open as native on android device but after a while when i open project on android device it open on android web browser device

for example i installed `@react-native-community/async-storage` module and after that i run expo project on android device so it opened on android web browser

here is the screenshot of expo app and when i touch on the project name it open to web browser:

[image]

[image]

is there any way to solve that?